# Create a mobile app that just points to URL

Tags: android, iphone, ios

This might sound little easy but unfortunately I couldn't find any tutorial. I am trying to make a simple mobile app (iOS and Android) where if u click the icon it opens a URL in mobile browser.

Is there an easy way I can do this an app that just installs icon and that icon when clicked open URL in mobile browser.

PS. I know bookmark option but I would like to have it as an app.

Thank you.

Comment: You want to make a browser or do u simply want to open a link from a button in the app ?

Comment: Just so I'm clear. You want the user to click an icon on their home screens and then launch a browser which will then load a url? I.e. You don't want an app to launch of your own?

Comment: You can use phonegap to do that. [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides)

Comment: yes just if you install the app an icon is created and when u click it browser open with a URL: http://example.com that's all.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you do it for android

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

This is how you do it for iOS

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the point, however I guess the following would work. You'd still have your app running in the background, as that is how Android lifecycle works.

So, I'd go ahead and create your default application with a 'blank' activity. Once done, all you'd have to do, is ensure that you launch the browser intent when the app is created. I haven't tested this code, but I'm sure it'll work (with little to no debugging):

You need to specify the url to browse to:

```
Uri urlToBrowse = Uri.parse("YOUR_URL_GOES_HERE");
```

Then you will need to create an intent for the browser:

```
Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, urlToBrowse);
```

Finally you'll need to start the new activity:

```
startActivity(browser);
```

Other than that, you'll have to play about with it. A little more information would have been wonderful, but this should get you started at least.

Comment: thankyou, the issue is i have a JQuery Mobile app and i like my customers to have it on their cell phones all the time rather than they give url like www.example.com/app. This is good for business too they will always be reminded of us when ever they need services related to us.