# Android and iOS mobile app that points to web app URL

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

### Goal

Let's say I have a fully responsive web app that's hosted at, say, http://example.com.

Now, I want to build a mobile app for **Android** and **iOS** that ***just points to*** my web app. i.e., When the user opens the app, it navigates them to example.com and that's it.

## Question

- What is the procedure for doing this?
- Are there any tools out there that make this simple?

#### Clarification

[This StackOverflow answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17059695/1640892):

> This is how you do it for Android:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,                                                         Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

> This is how you do it for iOS:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

But this question is asking for a ***simple procedure***. Perhaps with a simple CLI for Cordova, Android SDK, Xcode or something similar?

For example, [this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio) says you can access Android SDK tools from a command line at: `/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/`.

Comment: `cordova start myProject`, open the `config.xml`. change `index.html` to `http://www.example.com`. put `http://www.example.com` to your whitelist

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira: Thanks. Very helpful. But maybe you mean `cordova create myProject`?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry i use ionic CLI. ionic start same as cordova create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a good video that explains how to do this](https://youtu.be/LzlNP9nS6fo?t=11m1s) by going into Android SDK and doing everything manually.

https://youtu.be/LzlNP9nS6fo?t=11m1s

[Here is a link to the code](http://bitly.com/1wZTLxK).

http://bitly.com/1wZTLxK

Answer (score 0):

Summary from comments:

1. `$ cordova create myProject`
2. Open `config.xml`
3. Change `index.html` to `http://www.example.com`

[Here is the Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/cli/index.html).

Also, note that to use the CLI you must first install the SDKs for your target platforms. [Click here for the platform guides documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/platforms/index.html).

**Breaking news:** This doesn't work.